Hierarchical/Nested Facets
How can we return facets as a hierarchy?
 1. knowledge_area
    -Knowledge area 1
    -Knowledge area 2
    -Knowledge area 3
    -Knowledge area 4
    -Knowledge area 5 
 2. study_field
    -Study field 1 (kwnoledge area 1)
    -Study field 2 (kwnoledge area 1)
    -Study field 3 (kwnoledge area 1)
    -Study field 4 (kwnoledge area 1)
    -Study field 5 (kwnoledge area 1)
    -Study field 6 (kwnoledge area 2)
    -Study field 7 (kwnoledge area 2)
    -Study field 8 (kwnoledge area 2)
    -Study field 9 (kwnoledge area 2)
    -Study field 10 (kwnoledge area 3)
    -Study field 11 (kwnoledge area 4)
    -Study field 12 (kwnoledge area 5)

As you can see, study_field has a parent knowledge area. How can we achieve this?
Thanks!

You can use Pivot Faceting to achieve the same. Facet.pivot parameter needs to be added to the Solr Query as '&facet.pivot=parameter1,parameter2', which returns the nested structure as below.

You can find more details on the same here:
https://lucidworks.com/post/pivot-facets-inside-and-out/
Hope this helps!!!

Hi, thanks for you comment. Is it mandatory to integrate with Solr in sitecore search? I don't see how can I configure this on customer engagement console.

@Godiez Ya right that not available on Sitecore Search..But can be achived by running SOLR query using facet pivot parameter as above...Hope this helps!!!
